# Designing a current limiting circuit

Tags: current-limiting

I have an adapter with a rating of 5V and 4amps output. I have to create a circuit that can give two outputs of 5V 3amps(max) and 5V 1amp(max) using the adapter as a power source.

Comment: This is a very nice assignment. What is your [specific question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: If you show what you've done, highlight where you're stuck and ask a specific question you'll get lots of help. Dump an assignment on us and you'll get little.

Comment: Oh yeah? Cool story.

Comment: It is extremely hard to do what you ask exactly **BECAUSE** measuring or controlling the outputs causes voltage drop. 5V in - Vdrop  means there will be less than 5V out. In practice the drop can be made so small as to not matter in most cases. If eg you have a 10 milliOhm sense resistor then the 3A leg will drop V = IR = 3A x 0.01 Ohms = 30 mV or about 0.030V/5V  = 0.6% of the 5V input. If this is not acceptable you can sense current with eg a hall affect sensor. You then need a "switch - usually a MOSFET. This will need an Rdson (on resistance) low enough to drop acceptably low voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parallel circuit with two branches. Each branch will receive 5V. That's your two outputs. Use ohms law to calculate minimum load resistance that will use 3A for one branch and repeat in other branch for 1A. Practice calculating parallel resistance formula to check your total amp draw. Review Kirchhoff's voltage and current laws to get a sound idea of what is happening in the circuit. Cheers.